# How can I bind d3 map tooltips to Leaflet's popupPane?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, d3.js, z-index, leaflet

I've got an adaptation of [Crosslet](http://sztanko.github.io/crosslet/) that sets a few map layers on top of one another:

- Layer 1: Satellite Imagery tiles (In leaflet-tile-pane)
- Layer 2: D3-based vector Polygons (In leaflet-overlay-pane)
- Layer 3: Labels/Roads reference tiles (In leaflet-top-pane, added with [this method](https://github.com/wboykinm/geosprocket-labs/blob/master/d3/crosslet/crosslet.js#L1339-L1344))

**[Application here](http://wboykinm.github.io/geosprocket-labs/d3/crosslet/#14/40.7346/-74.1663)**

**[Source here](https://github.com/wboykinm/geosprocket-labs/tree/gh-pages/d3/crosslet)**

The problem with this is that the hover tooltips - bound to mouseover of the D3 polygons - are showing up *underneath* the reference tiles:

[image]

I've tried changing the z-index of [the hover tooltip element](https://github.com/wboykinm/geosprocket-labs/blob/master/d3/crosslet/less/crosslet.less#L226-L242), but the elements are sort of trapped within their respective panes. How can I bind the D3-generated popups to the leaflet [popup pane](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-popuppane)?

Thanks!

Comment: There's no `z-index` in SVG -- the elements are rendered in the order in which they appear. So if you want an element to appear on top, you have to make sure that it comes last in the DOM.

Comment: That explains why that doesn't work; but my question is exactly that: how can I add the <g class="hover"> element last (i.e. after the top-pane tiles)?

Comment: Run that code after the code that adds those tiles. Sorry to be not more specific, but your application is rather large.

Comment: Many apologies; I blame backbone :) But the <g class="hover"> element is _already_ [appended to the SVG](https://github.com/wboykinm/geosprocket-labs/blob/master/d3/crosslet/crosslet.js#L1372-L1374) after the tiles are [added to the top pane](https://github.com/wboykinm/geosprocket-labs/blob/master/d3/crosslet/crosslet.js#L1339-L1344).

Comment: Well, one sure way of doing it would be to create the SVG, append a `g` that will serve as root for everything else and then append the `g` for the hover elements. That is, all other methods wouldn't append to the SVG, but to the first `g`.

Comment: The .leaflet-top-pane {pointer-events: none;} saved me. I needed to keep interaction on my D3 pane while there was a label pane on top and this did the trick. cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the only way is to make yet another pane for the tooltips (layer 4) and hack the d3 tooltip code to add the element in that pane.

Comment: Off to hack. It's unfortunate that crosslet currently uses backbone.js, because it's woven through in ways that make it difficult for me to tease out the pane attachments.

Comment: Hey Mourner - is there an example of someone having appended **leaflet** popups to a different pane? I have the same problem as above when using leaflet vector layers underneath a reference overlay; the popups show up under the streets.